# viewport tag does not do anything on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, viewport

Like many others I have a problem with the landscape mode on the iPad. Portrait is fine, but rotating to landscape makes it zoom in to 200% and part of my webpage 'falls' of the screen unnecessary.

The relevant part of the webpage (a canvas to draw on using Javascript) is 823 x 690 px (CSS) and should fit nicely in the iPad's resolution of 2048 x 1536 (device).

I have found many answers suggesting to use something like (extended version):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, 
    minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Somehow this has no effect at all on the way the website is displayed in landscape mode AND portrait mode. The things I have tried are (following the many suggestions on internet):

- use only a limited number of viewport setting (e.g only width=device-width and initial-scale=1)
- use height=device-height instead of width=device-width
- use 1.0 instead of 1
- use other scaling factors like 0.5 or 2
- combinations of the above

It just doesn't matter what I do, nothing changes and I am really at a loss here and feel very stupid because it seems to work for everybody else.

Any idea what to do is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the iPad portrait and landscape does not inherently change the "zoom" (unless specifically told to do so through media queries in CSS or the meta tag; which you're not telling it to do).

First, start with the classic meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Second, there's no reference page, CSS, or HTML to check out the parent markup that's hosting your drawing canvas; but my assumption is the following:

You write:

> and should fit nicely in the iPad's resolution of 2048 x 1536 (device).

There's a difference between the iPad's device resolution and the webpage resolution. This is the difference between CSS pixels and device pixels (read more http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html). Long story short: even the iPad Air is still on a 1024x768 CSS pixel screen size. I suspect that your container divs are forcing a re-size / zoom or something that we simply can't see yet.

With more information I, or someone else here, can likely help further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the simple version just using width=device-width and initial-scale=1.0. Nothing changes. In my HTML and CSS I just use stuff like width: 823px; and height: 690px;and stuff like top, padding etc, nothing unusual.